# Random sorting in solr with boost to a specific field

Tags: sorting, random, solr, solr-boost

I want to sort documents randomly but give preference to a specific field.
I tried dynamic random field using RandomSortField field type

but sorting ignores scoring and boost factor becomes irrelevant in my condition.

Sorting with multiple condition does not work either.
sort=random_82423 asc,rating desc
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: It's not exactly what I think you're asking, but if you want to randomize results within each rating bucket:  `sort=rating desc,random_82423 desc`

Comment: I tried this, but its not working @PeterDixon-Moses